# Comparator doesn't swing, is there problem with circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, comparator

I made this circuit to switch signals based on the 3V regulator sourcing current out VDD (out connector J2), or seeing 3V on VDD coming in on J2. I put the diode to prevent back current into the regulator. I had hoped when sourcing current, R4 would drop 10mV for 10mA, and this would send the comparator high. But it is stuck low. Does anyone see any mistakes? The offset voltage of the comparator is 2mV.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TL331 datasheet section 9.2.2.1 says that your input voltage range can go up to Vcc-1.5V.  And if both exceed the allowed range the output will be low.

Maybe there is a part that includes the positive rail that (edit: fixed type) will work instead?  Or power it off 5V.

Comment: I totally see what you said. I saw 2mV offset voltage and didn't read thoroughly down below. I know I need to get my current mirror chops, then when I saw the circuit in the datasheet it might have hit me.

Answer (score 0):

It took me several minutes to find the comparator due to not using the proper symbol and one of the inputs being on the right (wrong) side instead of on the left.

Your question doesn't make it clear what this circuit is supposed to do and what "back voltage" means in this context? The schematic mentions "robot" so I suspect that you mean "back EMF" or reverse current when the motors are generating.

With D1 in place there will be no reverse current through R4. Both ends of R4 will be at the same potential and you may find that U5 does not switch.

In any case, your U4 voltage regulator cannot accept current back from the motor. In this regard it does not act as an ideal voltage source.

Comment: I rewrote my question. I see U5 won't switch when the 3V on J2 is present.

Comment: I understand now completely I need to follow IPC standards. I am self-taught, not company taught, and didn't realize this soon enough.